# Higher level CSS animation library?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I looked around but can't find any good resources for doing higher level animations (like card flip, cubes, etc).  Like a ???:CSS :: jQuery:JS.

I know of [transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) but I'm looking for something that has more functionality and animations built in.

Comment: First hit on DuckDuckGo: http://patorjk.com/blog/2011/06/13/css3-card-flip-animation-trick/ and http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

Comment: Today I published a mini tutorial about CSS3 transitions and animations. You could find it: http://css3-magic.brunoscopelliti.com, here.
I think it's worth to be seen. All the code is shared on Codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/)? Seems pretty good. Another good one seems like [CSS3 Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/css3-animations-plugin/launch) and for stuff like card-flipping, [CSS3 Playground](http://css3playground.com/).

Answer (score 0):

An edited version of this one: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/:

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PnUHr/1/

**CSS**

```
#f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="f1_container">
    <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="Cirques.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
            <img src="Cirques.jpg" style="transform:scaleX(-1), transform:scaleY(-1)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All credits go to the original created (see link). I've just removed the padding that was on the back-facing `<div>` and added a mirrored background of the front-facing image.

For Mozilla/Gecko browsers you need to add the `-moz-*` prefixes too. Same for Opera (`-o-*) and Internet Explorer (`-ms-*`).

Direct image link: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Cirques.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[Effeckt.css](http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/) is STILL work in progress but look very promising– a pattern libary of multiple sources.